# Android Studio 4.1.2 + Kotlin 1.4.30

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

For example I have this kotlin code in editor:

```
... 
val field == MySocket.ParamVer
...
```

Then when I type another dot after MySocket (result is "MySocket..ParamVer") Android Studio dont't show list of fields and methods of the class MySocket as I expected.
I have to firstly type space after MySocket (result in "MySocket .ParamVer") and after then type dot letter (result in "MySocket. .ParamVer") - only then Android Studio show list of fields and methods.

But when I am editing java source codes, when I press dot (in "MySocket.ParamVer" after word "MySocket") then list of fields and methods is immediatelly showed.

Exist any settings in Android Studio which enables the same behavior for editing kotlin source codes which is for java source codes? Or is it problem Kotlin plugin? Or where can I report this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the setting you want to add is in : File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> "Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys" If this isn't the behavior you want you'll need to clarify a bit more what you need

Edit: Ctrl + Space will open the auto-completion menu

Comment: No, it's not it. Still after type dot letter after "MySocket" in text "MySocket.ParamVer" in editor is not automatically showed list of fields  and methods of the class "MySocket".

Comment: Are your methods / fields  public or static

Comment: Are public. But with this is not problem. When I type MySocket and then press dot then editor show list of fields and methods. But when I type dot into existing  "MySocket.ParamVer" (on the position of the existing dot) then editor don't show list of fields and methods.

Comment: I am not aware of any option in Android Studio being able to do this unfortunatly.

Comment: However, you can use ctrl + space to show auto-completion immediatly

Comment: Ctrl + space working. Thanks. But dot (java style) would be better. It's pressing only one key.